# "Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped" showing when facebook debuging my url

Tags: facebook, seo, share

the problem happen when am try to share url of my site in facebook. so i debug my url using facebook debug. showing this error
"Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped".

[sample url of my site](http://filmygossips.in/videos/bollywood/trailer/detective-byomkesh-bakshy-teaser-trailer)

Comment: Please share more details including a part of the code that is causing the error .

Comment: @arkoak :Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed - Bad Response Code URL returned a bad HTTP response code.